# How to format array with relations parent-child?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have the typical structure of table in MySQL.

```
id | parent_id | name | object_id 
1    0           G      1
2    1           T      1
3    1           R      1
```

How to build result array with values of parent/child when I select data by `object_id`?

Comment: Please elaborate your question more.

Comment: How do you want your resulting array?

Comment: I dont know how to relative data, so take off all by object_id and after iterate this in script?

Comment: Have a look: https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset

Comment: you should make tree like structure along depth for such type of data. 
In laravel you can use associative arrays for this.

Comment: An alternative package to **laravel-nestedset** would be https://github.com/gazsp/baum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its laravel and the parent and the object are both Eloquent models you should be able to do something like this:

```
class Parent{
    public function children(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Object', 'your_table', 'parent_id, 'object_id');
    }

}
```

And then the child object class:

```
class object{
       public function parent(){
            return $this->belongsToMany('App\Parent', 'your_table', 'object_id, 'parent_id');
        }

}
```

Look into eloquent relationships here: [Eloquent relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
If its any other way you are looking for the comments above surely might help you in the correct direction.